# Can we print only the directories of branch/latest in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

How can we print only the directories of branch latest in clearcase .

Comment: I see I have answered ClearCase questions for you before. Were any of those answers helpful? Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer? (or http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: You have posted an "answer" which was actually a question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30589454). Why not read http://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how Stack Overflow is working?

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?resultof=%22find%22%20) command in your view (which already selects the right version, like the `LATEST` from a branch):

```
cleartool find -type d -print
```

The '`-type d`' option will restrict the search for directory elements only.

More generally, in any view, you can try (see "[general examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425#general-examples)")

```
cleartool find . -type d -version version(.../yourBranch/LATEST) -print
# or
cleartool find . -type d -element version(.../yourBranch/LATEST) -print
```

The `.../` notation allows you to search for a version in `yourBranch`, without having to specify parent branches (like `/main/yourBranch` or `/main/anotherBranch/yourBranch`)

---

If you want just the name, and or more details, use the [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) in a [`cleartool describe`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) command:

Replace the `-print` with

```
# Windows syntax
-exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""

# Unix syntax
-exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%n\n" "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```